# How to find out if a schedulable class was ever executed or is scheduled to be at all?

Tags: apex, scheduled-apex, scheduled-job, status

I am considering removing a field, which is no more needed, but I found it is used in a class, that I am not familiar with. It is a schedulable one and I first looked at the scheduled jobs in Setup, where I found nothing related to it. At the same time I saw in the dev console there are 4 CronTrigger items that it is referenced by. Then I used the following query:

`SELECT Id, CreatedById, CreatedDate, Status, CompletedDate, LastProcessed, JobType, JobItemsProcessed, NumberOfErrors, TotalItemJobs FROM AsyncApexJob WHERE ApexClass.Name = [name of my class]`

It gave me the result in the attachment. As it is still in Queued status, my assumption is that it has never run. I did not manage to find information whether the 0s in JobItemsProcessed, NumberOfErrors and TotalItemJobs confirm that. To me it seems the class was never used and is also not scheduled to run in the future, but I am looking for a 100% confirmation.

[image: Result of query]